# How to import one day old logs

Tags: python, logging, import, scripting

I am new to Python and need some help in being able to import done day old logs.  Below is the script I have come up with, but not sure if it is working or if there is a better way to do this.

```
def fileCreation(path):  
    now = time.time()  
    oneday_ago = now - (24*60*60) ## seconds in 1 day  
    if fileCreation < oneday_ago:  
        print f  
        getAuditRecords(f)
```

I have a script that does import the whole database from mid June 2014 but only need to get day old logs.

Here is a sample of the logs I am trying to import

> /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_982_2.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_20_1.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_29962_1.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_15593_2.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_9946_1.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_10746_1.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_6508_1.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_17340_2.xml.201409070400
>   /mnt/hcp1/SCC/SCC_ora_18881_2.xml.201407090400

Comment: We need to see a sample of your log data

Comment: ... and the definition of `f`.

Comment: First, you're comparing `fileCreation`, which is your function object, to the time two days ago. That obviously isn't going to work. You have to compare the file creation time, not your function object.

Comment: Second, looking for files created before than now - 2 days is obviously not going to find one-day-old logs.

Comment: @abarnert  can ask what you mean with the comparing comment? thanks

Comment: You've written `if fileCreation < twodays_ago:`. What is `fileCreation`? It's your function. What does it mean for a function to be less than a time? It's like asking whether red is less than ice cream.

Comment: @abarnert  As sated at beginning of post I am new to this, sorry for asking "dumb" questions.  But how do you do the "compare the file creation time"

Comment: @AliGajani  sample log has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare the file creation time to one day ago, you need to actually *get* the file creation time. Your code is using `fileCreation`, the function; it doesn't mean anything useful to ask whether that function is less than some time.

---

Unfortunately, "file creation time" is not a portable concept. If you really want that, you need to write different code for different platforms, which I won't explain.

Usually, you're happy with "file modification time". This is set when the file is created, and updated only when you overwrite or append to the file. You can use [`getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to read this. So:

```
def fileCreation(path):
    now = time.time()
    oneday_ago = now - (24*60*60) ## seconds in 1 day
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    if mtime < oneday_ago:
        print f
        getAuditRecords(f)
```

---

However, it looks like there's a timestamp attached to each filename. If `/mnt/hcp1/R1P/R1P_ora_982_2.xml.201409070400` means that the file was created on 7 September 2014 at 04:00 (and if the timezones, etc. aren't an issue), you may want to consider parsing those strings instead of `stat`ting the file.

And once you're parsing date strings, you might as well use the simpler and higher-level [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library instead of the lower-level `time`. (You could do this with the previous version too, but since `getmtime` returns a `time`-style timestamp, you'd have to convert it manually to use it as a `datetime`, so there's less advantage.)

So:

```
def fileCreation(path):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    oneday_ago = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    fileext = os.path.splitext(path)[1][1:]
    filetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(fileext, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
    if filetime < oneday_ago:
        print f
        getAuditRecords(f)
```

---

(Also, I'm not sure what that `f` is. Maybe you meant `path`?)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "two days ago" part, you should use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`

E.g.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
two_days = datetime.timedelta(days=2)
two_days_ago = now - two_days
```